# Using include to replace iframe php error

Tags: php, yii2-advanced-app, php-7.2

I'm trying to use include to replace iframe in my php but I get an error

```
include(/yii2cta/frontend/web/commenti/view?pc=71): failed to open stream: No error
```

I don't want to use ajax or jquery load because my javascript code broke if I do so after I did search on internet I found that I can use include or "file_get_contents", in my php code for both include and file_get_contents i get the error 
my code is :

```
<?php 
$url = Url::to(['/commenti/view', 'pc' => $model->post_id]);
include($url);
?>
```

the url is

```
/yii2cta/frontend/web/commenti/view?pc=71
```

if I use iframe it work but I don't want to use iframe 
But I don't know if it possible to use include or file_get_contents ?

Comment: missing quotes? `include('/yii2cta/frontend/web/commenti/view?pc=71')`

Comment: but the url is in a variable if I use quotes it will become string

Comment: yeah.. sorry.. saw it too late

Comment: :) no problem ; and thanks for trying